# How to instantiate a new map with proj4leaflet projections from a Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, proj4js, bootstrap-framework

I'm currently working on a Leaflet website that will be able to display GPS-Tracks with different projections. Now I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu based on Bootstrap, where I can set different coordinate reference systems (CRS), see code below:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projections<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Switzerland</li>
                <li><a href="#">LV95</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">RT90</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Sweden</li>
                <li><a href="#">SWEREF99TM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SWEREF99</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ST74</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

For example, I have the Swiss LV95 CRS, among others, in a separate .js file from which I would like to call it. This is an example of how to call a proj4leaflet CRS when instantiating a new map:

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {
crs: LV95
});

L.tileLayer('http://api.geosition.com/tile/osm-bright-3006/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: crs.options.resolutions.length,
  minZoom: 0,
  continuousWorld: true,
  attribution: 'Map data © <a      href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>, Imagery © 2013 <a href="http://www.kartena.se/">Kartena</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

So when I click on the "LV95" Dropdown element, it instantiates a new map with the respective CRS overwriting the old var map = L.map.

Are there any efficient implementation ideas or critique for my approach?